# What is the mathematical/CS framework for understanding Stackoverflow's Bounty System?

Tags: math

The idea that one gives some of his credits to get an answer for a question seems simple enough but when applied to a whole network of millions of users each with varying reputations it seems like some rigorous checks and balances have to be applied. What is the math framework on which this stuff is based?

Answer (score 5):

There's no math behind the bounty system. It's just rules that are described in the FAQ - https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty

Comment: This assumes that the rules are arbitrary. The question is about why those rules were chosen...and if there is any framework for such choices other than only trial and error

Comment: I think it's just trial and error. If you check on meta, you should find various questions that led to the current system.

Comment: How do i post a bounty on one of my questions?

Answer (score 0):

The mathematical basis of this system would be simple addition and subtraction. Why the range was chosen is probably more because of economics rather than math. Supply and demand ... The demand is high and the supply has been found to be low, therefore the "price" will be relatively high.  50 to 500 reputation points is the reward set which may be construed as "relatively high" to enough consumers(answerers) to make it worth their time and effort to "purchase" the reputation points with a good answer.  The bounty could also be construed as a marketing ploy to help market the product, thereby achieving the sale; which again is the sought after good answer.  This bounty system is therefore a great example of market economics; and in the past, it was often noted that one's "reputations" is worth more than money.